# Сортировка данных в tableView по дате и времени

Tags: массивы, swift, struct, datepicker

у меня есть структура TaskModel, в которой есть свойство date: String? (тут хранится и дата и время с datePicker). Каждый экземпляр структуры хранится в массиве tasksArray, данные из этого массива попадают в tableView. Также данные в массиве хранятся следующим образом:

```
private var tasksArray: [TaskModel] {
       
       get {
           guard let encodedData = defaults.array(forKey: key) as? [Data] else {
                   return []
               }
           
               return encodedData.map { try! JSONDecoder().decode(TaskModel.self, from: $0)
                   
               }
           
       }

       set {
           
           let data = newValue.map { try? JSONEncoder().encode($0) }
               defaults.set(data, forKey: key)
   }

   }
```

Подскажите, как можно отсортировать данные в таблице по дате?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сразу отсортировать массив tasksArray в get. Добавьте в продолжение функции map sorted (разверните optional date, если нужно):

```
return encodedData.map { try! JSONDecoder().decode(TaskModel.self, from: $0) }.sorted(by: {$0.date < $1.date})
```

Comment: не cработало, может потому что дата в формате String

Comment: Не сработало как, ошибку пишет или ничего не изменилось?

Comment: никаких изменений не произошло

Comment: Вы можете в get перед return проверить какой массив получается в итоге, меняется он или нет. Насчет изменений - возможно нужно сделать tableView.reloadData()